# Spring JPA/Hibernate Composite key generation in PrePersist, Custom Generator or Service Layer?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a legacy database and I'm developing a Spring MVC application with JPA/Hibernate. My problem comes with the generation of the composite primary keys. An example of primary key is composed like this:

**Serial, Year, OrderID, LineId**

LineId will be generated based on the **max(LineId)** for each tuple of Serial, Year and LineId.

I've thought about the following ways:

---

- **PrePersist Listener**: It means the listener would have to access repositories and even maybe have references to other entities in order to get the next id. EDIT: Hibernate Docs say: `A callback method must not invoke EntityManager or Query methods!`.  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html#d0e3013
- **Custom Generator**: I haven't found a single example that shows how to access the entity's instance to retrieve the properties I need to do a proper select.
- **Service Layer**: Would be just too verbose.
- **Overriding the Spring's Data's JPA Repository save() method implmentation**: In this case, Here we could access the entity's instance properties.

---

What is the ***correct*** way to achieve this purpose? Thanks

Comment: I suggest to go with the save method on the repository, if every save goes through this method. You just need to enforce that this method is used everywhere when the entity is stored. This is the power of DAO/repository pattern - it gives you possibilities to modify standard behavior of entityManger to suite your needs.

Comment: Having a compound primary keys is a REALLY bad idea, so ideally you would go back and add an ID column to the legacy database and make the current compound key a unique index instead. Unfortunately the world is often far from ideal, but your current use-case falls outside the scope of JPA features supported directly by JPA. If other applications are inserting data into the table, then there are no good solutions. If your application is the only client of the database, then I would use a factory to create the entities (with an id), and pre-allocate Ids, like the Table/Sequence generator does.

Answer (score 0):

What I have often done to support this is to use a domain-driven design technique where I control this at the time I associate an `OrderLine` to the `Order`.

```
public class Order {
  private List<OrderLine> lines;

  // don't allow the external world to modify the lines collection.
  // forces them to use domain driven API exposed below.
  public List<OrderLine> getLines() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList( lines );
  }

  // avoid allowing external sources to set the lines collection
  // Hibernate can set this despite the method being private.
  private void setLines(List<OrderLine> lines) {
    this.lines = lines;
  }

  public OrderLine addLine(String serial, Integer year) {
    final OrderLine line = new OrderLine( this, serial, year );
    lines.add( line );
    return line;
  }

  public void removeLine(Integer lineId) {
    lines.removeIf( l -> l.getId().getLineId().equals( lineId ) );
  }
}

public OrderLine {
  public OrderLine() {
  }

  OrderLine(Order order, String serial, Integer year) {
    this.id = new OrderLineId( order.getLines().size() + 1, serial, year, order.getId() );
  }
}
```

The only code which ever calls the special `OrderLine` constructor is called from `Order` and you make sure that you always delegate the addition and removal of `OrderLine` entities through the aggregate root, `Order`.

This also implies you only ever need to expose an `Order` repository and you manipulate the lines associated with an `Order` only through an `Order` and never directly.